How to make my SwiftUI View accentable for widget?
This is how I defined my simple view:
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
    Text("my simple text in first line")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .font(.caption)
        .padding(10)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .widgetAccentable()
    Text("my simple text in second line")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.caption)
            .opacity(0.7)
            .lineLimit(5)
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color.gray)
            .widgetAccentable()
    Spacer()
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

and the result is following:


How to make it with black color as background and green (tinted) text? Is it possible? The same way as it with icons below.

The way widgetAccentable works is that it treats the view on which you applied it as a mask, and applies the accent across all the non-transparent regions of the view. By having .background(.gray) on both of the Texts, you essentially remove all the transparent regions, so the entirety of widget is tinted, and you can't see the text.
So just remove .background(.gray). If you want the widget to have a different background, you can put .background(...) after widgetAccentable.
Do note that a lot of the colors get ignored when in a tinted widget. For a gray color, .gray shows up as a white color. You should use something like .fill.tertiary instead.
Here is an example where I put background(.fill.tertiary) on the first line of text, after widgetAccentable,
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
    Text("my simple text in first line")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .font(.caption)
        .padding(10)
        .widgetAccentable()
        .background(.fill.tertiary)
    Text("my simple text in second line")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.caption)
            .opacity(0.7)
            .lineLimit(5)
            .padding(10)
            .widgetAccentable()
    Spacer()
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)



Oww, I need to study your answer... Thank you;)

One more thing. Is there a way to PREVENT from tinting that view even when tinted option is selected?

I have added .widgetAccentable(false).background(Color.gray) but it is still coloured with white instead of gray. Why?

@BartłomiejSemańczyk Oh you mean the fact that it ignores regular colors. I don't think you can change that. In the tinted rendering mode, most colors don't work. Everything is either accented or not accented. You cannot use whatever color you like. From what I have seen, only "semantic colors" like .fill.tertiary work.

@BartłomiejSemańczyk And to be honest, that's the whole point of a tinted home screen isn't it? Note that you can still access the variants of the user-selected accent color. For example, Text("Foo").widgetAccentable().background(.fill.tertiary).widgetAccentable(). This shows a text with a background slightly different from the text's own colour.

@BartłomiejSemańczyk After some looking-around, you can use your own colors if you put them in an Image, by drawing things using this initialiser for example. Then you can apply .widgetAccentedRenderingMode(.fullColor) on that Image. But this is really going against the design principles of widgets.

No no. I need to redesign it and use it with design principles.

@BartłomiejSemańczyk Yeah, you should probably redesign your widget. Apple recommends that you don't use specific colors to convey information.
